# python time.sleep takes longer than expected (multi threaded)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, sleep

I've gone through related threads on `time.sleep()` hang/delays but didn't find an answer yet. Hence, posting the question with the issue I'm seeing.

I don't have access to the complete code. Here's the code snippet that I've access to and am seeing the issue:

```
def my_debug(self, msg):
    logging.debug(msg, extra={'threadname':threading.currentThread().name})

while True:
    next = time.time() + INTERVAL # INTERVAL = 5
    my_debug("Triggering event")
    # some code
    # some more code
    sleep_time = max(next - time.time(), 0)
    my_debug("Sleeping for %d sec" % sleep_time)
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

This produces:

```
2017-01-11 00:08:03 DEBUG MainThread Sleeping for 4 sec
2017-01-11 00:08:21 DEBUG MainThread Triggering event
```

Apparently, there are other threads and the while loop executes in the MainThread. time.sleep is supposed to sleep for 4 seconds whereas it ended up waiting for 18 seconds.

I am looking for possible reasons/scenarios that can cause this behaviour.

Any help/pointers would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This fabricated example can reproduce your results.
Another thread changes the global `sleep_time` just in between calculating and printing it. There is no locking:

```
import logging
import time
import threading


INTERVAL = 5

logging.basicConfig(filename='thread.log',level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')

def my_debug(msg):
    logging.debug(msg, extra={'threadname':threading.currentThread().name})


class Changer(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        global sleep_time
        while True:
            sleep_time = 18


changer = Changer()
changer.start()


while True:
    next = time.time() + INTERVAL # INTERVAL = 5
    my_debug("Triggering event")
    # some code
    # some more code
    sleep_time = max(next - time.time(), 0)
    my_debug("Sleeping for %f sec" % sleep_time)
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

Content of `thread.log`:

```
2017-02-11 19:45:14,700 Triggering event
2017-02-11 19:45:14,701 Sleeping for 4.999720 sec
2017-02-11 19:45:32,705 Triggering event
2017-02-11 19:45:32,705 Sleeping for 4.999525 sec
2017-02-11 19:45:50,710 Triggering event
2017-02-11 19:45:50,710 Sleeping for 4.999726 sec
2017-02-11 19:46:08,714 Triggering event
2017-02-11 19:46:08,716 Sleeping for 4.997533 sec
2017-02-11 19:46:26,720 Triggering event
2017-02-11 19:46:26,725 Sleeping for 4.995042 sec
2017-02-11 19:46:44,730 Triggering event
2017-02-11 19:46:44,731 Sleeping for 4.999471 sec
2017-02-11 19:46:49,730 Triggering event
2017-02-11 19:46:49,731 Sleeping for 4.999794 sec
2017-02-11 19:47:07,736 Triggering event
2017-02-11 19:47:07,736 Sleeping for 4.999609 sec
2017-02-11 19:47:25,739 Triggering event
2017-02-11 19:47:25,739 Sleeping for 4.999751 sec
```

Note that I format the wait as float to avoid losing nearly one second in the output.

Comment: That code would have already executed. If you look at the logs, the two log lines are consecutive (last line of loop and 2nd line of loop) with a sleep in between.

Comment: Can you add a few more lines of the log file.

Comment: I don't have it at the moment (as I mentioned I've limited access). I'm trying to gather some more details.

Comment: Came up with an example that reproduces your log file.

Comment: Thanks Mike. In my case, there are no global variables though.

Comment: It is a guessing game without more of the relevant code.